# What does 'as many think' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> I am not a member of that club, as many think, nor even nearly related to it.

How should I understand the phrase 'as many think'? It delivers the meaning that many people think that I belong to the club, or that I don't belong to it?

Comment: "...as many (people) (may) think..." is the full phrase, if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The writer is stating that s/he is not a member of a club. In fact, they are not "even nearly related to it." However, by adding "as many think," the writer means, as you guessed, that many other think the writer is a member of the club.

With this sentence, the writer is disavowing any connection to the club, while acknowledging that this disavowal is unexpected.

> It delivers the meaning that many people think that I belong to the club, or that I don't belong to it?

[TL;DR](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209439/what-does-tldr-mean-and-how-is-it-used): Yes, and yes. This sentence says both.